# I make myself in seven

Tags: riddle

> I make myself in seven,
>   If I come after second
>   Then I precede
>   I can be closed or shut
>   I can be purple
>   In time I'm 120

**What am I?**

Comment: Welcome to puzzling! By putting two spaces after each line, you create a line break

Comment: Be sure to accept the answer here.

Answer (score 15):

I think it might be

> /fɔː/

More specifically

> Four, for, and fore

I make myself in seven,

> In seven segment display, the number four is made up of four lines.

If I come after second
Then I precede

> B is the second letter, and BEFORE means to precede.

I can be closed or shut

> (Thanks @Mithrandir!) They can be written with a slanted top or an open top

I can be purple

> The four ball in snooker is purple

In time I'm 120

> 4 is 120 degrees away from 12 on a clock

Comment: This is correct. Think about how you write four for the missing line.